# Problems using ClickHouse

Tags: search, case-insensitive, druid, clickhouse

We are revamping our existing system, which uses MYSQL DB to deal with the following type of data.

- transaction and order related data
- customers information
- products information

We need to query on these data and pull in statistical data, and also filter, facet and segment list and KPIs.

We tried ClickHouse, Druid, DGraph did a few tests on sample data to benchmark and to check which DB fits our needs.

Few things I liked about Druid DB are,

- Druid Search Queries: Which lists down all the matches along with the dimensions(column names) and count/occurrence for the same.
  Link: http://druid.io/docs/latest/querying/searchquery.html
- utf8mb4 support
- Full text search
- Case insensitive search

We found ClickHouse to be faster when compared to MYSQL and Druid databases. But have the following problems.

- Unable to do druid-like-search queries (which return dimension and occurrences). Any workaround to achieve this?
- Case insensitive search. How do we handle this? ClickHouse is case-sensitive, right?
- utf8mb4 support? How do we save/store special characters or few emoji's which are not supported on utf8?

  We had similar issues in MYSQL, and changing the collation to utf8mb4 solved it. What do we in ClickHouse to achieve this?

Your suggestions can help us overcome these challenges and make a better decision.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Case insensitive ILIKE operator was added to CH starting with version 20.6.3.28 - https://stackoverflow.com/a/64035230/303298.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Unable to do druid-like-search queries (which return dimension and occurrences). Any workaround to achieve this?

That feature sounds to work roughly like:

```
SELECT interval, dim1, COUNT(*) FROM my_table WHERE condition GROUP BY interval, dim1
UNION ALL
SELECT interval, dim2, COUNT(*) FROM my_table WHERE condition GROUP BY interval, dim2
UNION ALL
...
```

> Case insensitive search. How do we handle this? ClickHouse is case-sensitive, right?

There are multiple options, for example `positionCaseInsensitiveUTF8(haystack, needle)` function or match with regular expressions: https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/query_language/functions/string_search_functions/#match-haystack-pattern

> utf8mb4 support? How do we save/store special characters or few emoji's which are not supported on utf8?

Strings in ClickHouse are arbitrary byte sequences, so you can store whatever you want there, but you should probably check whether the available functions match your usecase.

Comment: Hi @Ivan Blinkov, thank you for your reply. But the query above: where you have mentioned dim1 and dim2, I shouldn't be identifying it and querying the same. Druid search identifies and returns the same(dimensions and occurrences) on its own, and then if needed I may want to query on a specific dimension/occurrence from the list(response from search-query). This  is something I want to achieve in ClickHouse as well.

Comment: @AnishNair I still don't see how it's fundamentally different since table structure is fixed and you know all of them in advance anyway. If your use case is more like unknown key-value pairs, you can put them into [Nested](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/data_types/nested_data_structures/nested/) column and then just ARRAY JOIN + GROUP BY over it.

Answer (score 0):

> Case insensitive search. How do we handle this? ClickHouse is
> case-sensitive, right?

This [blog](https://www.tinybird.co/blog-posts/text-search-at-scale-with-clickhouse) might be useful. Specifically:

> Adding (?i) at the beginning of every pattern makes it case-insensitive, like we did before:

```sql
SELECT
    id,
    job_title,
    multiMatchAllIndices(description, ['(?i)python', '(?i)javascript', '(?i)postgres']) AS indices,
    company
FROM jobs
WHERE length(indices) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

ClickHouse outperforms Druid by a large margin on relative time according to this report from ClickBench (https://benchmark.clickhouse.com/). I would also recommend StarRocks, another OLAP solution that is faster than ClickHouse. It is worth mentioning that StarRocks primarily focuses on OLAP (Online Analytical Processing) workloads with support for real-time analytics. So if you prioritize high-performance analytical queries and real-time insights, StarRocks could be a fantastic choice for you alongside Druid and ClickHouse.

Another thing worth noting is that StarRocks does support the utf8mb4 character set, utf8mb4 characters stored in StarRocks won’t get truncated or appear garbled. You can store and retrieve data containing a wide range of characters including emojis as well using StarRocks with relative ease.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).