# How to search the string in query with case insensitive on Clickhouse database?

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I am developing site using PHP and backend ClickHouse database. When i using like queries , it is not supporting case-sensitive words.

```
select id,comments from discussion where  comments LIKE "%Data not reflect%";
```

Is there any way to search case-insensitive words?

Comment: Look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55539778/303298

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no `ILIKE` operator. I think you can use `lowerUTF8()`.

```sql
select id,comments from discussion where lowerUTF8(comments) LIKE '%Data not reflect%';
```

However, might be performance heavy as it will have to convert all `comments` values to lowercase.

Comment: Received exception from server (version 19.1.6):
Code: 47. DB::Exception: Received from 192.168.**.**:9000. DB::Exception: Unknown identifier: %Data not reflect%, context: required_names: '%Data not reflect%' 'id' 'comments' source_tables: 'discussion' table_aliases: private_aliases: column_aliases: public_columns: 'comments' 'id' masked_columns: array_join_columns: source_columns: 'id' 'comments' .

Comment: Sorry, you should use single quotes. I copied your query and did not notice it. Updating my answer.

Comment: Yes. its working. But it may be slow the performance. For temproraily I can use it.

Answer (score 12):

Case insensitive **ILIKE** operator was added to CH starting with [version 20.6.3.28](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/whats-new/changelog/2020#clickhouse-release-v206328-stable):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT '** Data not reflect **' AS text
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '** data not reflect **'
)
WHERE text ILIKE '%Data not reflect%'

/*
┌─text───────────────────┐
│ ** Data not reflect ** │
│ ** data not reflect ** │
└────────────────────────┘
*/
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `positionCaseInsensitive` or `positionCaseInsensitiveUTF8`

Just like that

```
SELECT id,comments
FROM discussion
WHERE positionCaseInsensitive(comments,'Data not reflect')>0;
```

For more complicated patterns you can use regular expression with `i` flag inside:

```
SELECT ... WHERE match(comment, '(?i)Data.*not reflect');
```

See documentation: https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/query_language/functions/string_search_functions/#position-haystack-needle-locate-haystack-needle